# Use a parameter value in expr in Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

How we pass variable which is a floating-point value to spark expr?

```
myVariable=0.50;


expr("data.mark = myVariable")
```

This is what I expect after substituting myVariable.

```
expr("data.mark = 0.50"). --- value 0.50 should be used during execution .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation? Like so:

```
expr(String.format("data.mark = %s", myVariable))
```

Comment: Does java support adding s? I get a compilation error.

Comment: My answer was for Scala. I have updated it for Java now.

Comment: No it is java unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This is one way I found to do it, making f string. Two input variables within an expression.

```
beginDate = '2000-01-01'
endDate = '2050-12-31'
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ["id"])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "date", 
    explode(expr(f"sequence(to_date('{beginDate}'), to_date('{endDate}'), interval 1 day)"))
)
```